# Appropriate language for single result on last page

Tags: pagination, wording

I am working on a website that has paged search results.  At the top of each page, I am showing where the user is in the set of pages, using the typical "Showing X - Y of Z results" language (with an edge case for a single page).

For the sake of this question, let's assume that my particular search has 16 results, and I am showing 5 per page.

Therefore the page headings will have

- Page 1 => Showing 1-5 of 16 results.
- Page 2 => Showing 6-10 of 16 results.
- Page 3 => Showing 11-15 of 16 results.
- Page 4 => Showing 16-16 of 16 results.

Snap.  That last page heading is pretty bad.

I am contemplating using

- Showing last of 16 results.

or perhaps

- Showing 16 of 16 results.

but neither of these are sitting well.

Is there a common, well-worn wording for this situation?  I have not come across one, and have been unable to contrive paged results on various sites to see what is in use.

Comment: I'd mimic Google

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
Showing 16 of 16 results.
```

Remember, the purpose of the label is to help the user.  They don't care that it is tied to a paging control, so don't fall into the trap of thinking that you have to phrase the label within the context of a paging control.

If there are not enough results to trigger paging, then the line above tells the user "Don't worry everything you see is all there is."